# How to upload one file to several different directories using one FtpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, load-balancing

I'm using FTP servers on the Load Balanced FTP cluster. I need to put related files to a single server.

Can I upload one file to several different directories by one FtpWebRequest?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far?

Comment: I have not figured out how to change the URI for the existing FtpWebRequest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't**. First of all since the ftp protocol is intended to works on request basis, and second, since each FtpWebRequest has a specific path, you need to create a request for each directory in which you want to upload.

Comment: So I have no any way to guarantee uploading related files to the same FTP server?

Comment: It's possible that you could try to set the KeepAlive property to true for all your related files, but I can't say if that will keep all the files on the same machine. It's worth a try, though, if you can. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20326576/2463738

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue using **KeepAlive** property of FtpWebRequest. While KeepAlive is true all files from different requests will be uploaded to a single server.